# Bootstrap3 mvc 5 - center form div

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a headache from this design.
How I can separate a little bit in inline form label and textbox which belongs to form-control class.
I've tried everything, and margin and align-text, but I didnt find solution
Here is a photo:
[image: Lable go over the text box]
Here is the code:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9">
            <br />
            <h2 style="margin-top:100px;text-align:center">
               APPLY FOR INTERNSHIP PROGRAM
            </h2>
          </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, "Surname", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, "Location", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @*@Html.DropDownList("LocationID", null, "--Choose location--", new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LocationID, ViewBag.LocationID as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-----Select Category-----", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mail, "E-mail", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telephone, "Telephone number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telephone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartEduYear, "Entrance study year", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StartEduYear, ViewBag.StartYearFaculty as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartEduYear, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div><br />
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnglishLang.NameLang, "English level", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.DropDownList("EngID", null, "--Choose level--", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EngID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Faculty.FacultyName, "Faculty", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FacultyID, ViewBag.FacultyID as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "--Select a faculty--", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FacultyID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AvgScore, "Average score", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AvgScore, ViewBag.AverScore as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AvgScore, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GradYear, "Graduation year", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GradYear, ViewBag.GradYear as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GradYear, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WExp, "Work Experience", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.WExp, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WExp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Interests, "Interests", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Interests, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Interests, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>




            <span>Did you have any additional trainings?</span>
            <label for="chkYes">
                <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" onclick=" ShowHideDiv() " />Yes
            </label>
            <label for="chkNo">
                <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPassPort" onclick=" ShowHideDiv() " />No
            </label>
            <div class="form-group" id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Trainings, "Trainings", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Trainings, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Trainings, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <p></p>
            <span>Did you have any projects recently?</span>
            <label for="chkYes">
                <input type="radio" id="chkYes1" name="chkPassPort1" onclick=" ShowHideDiv() " />Yes
            </label>
            <label for="chkNo">
                <input type="radio" id="chkNo1" name="chkPassPort1" onclick=" ShowHideDiv() " />No
            </label>

            <div class="form-group" id="dvExample" style="display: none">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Projects, "Projects", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Projects, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Projects, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <p></p>
            <span>Have you been in some students organization?</span>
            <label for="chkYes">
                <input type="radio" id="chkYes2" name="chkPassPort2" onclick=" ShowHideDiv() " />Yes
            </label>
            <label for="chkNo">
                <input type="radio" id="chkNo2" name="chkPassPort2" onclick=" ShowHideDiv() " />No
            </label>
            <div class="form-group" id="dvExample1" style="display: none">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudOrg, "Organizations", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.StudOrg, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudOrg, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Apply" class="btn btn-default" style="text-align: center" />
        </div>

            @*<div class="form-group">
                    sdsdsdsd
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LccVRcTAAAAADLo_LxSj4mQzt9jLrgbo5L9wZ-J"></div>
                    <div>sdsdsds11
                        @if (TempData["recaptcha"] != null)
                        {
                            <p>@TempData["recaptcha"]</p>
                        }
                    </div>

                </div>*@

            @*<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">


                <div class="form-group">1231
                    @Html.Recaptcha()
                </div>


                </div>*@

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: We would need to see your css, that's what controls the styling

Comment: @Dareen Sweeney the CSS is the default by MVC5. I could attach it, but it consists app.4000 lines :(

Comment: Ok, I guess you mean bootstrap... Then I recommend you read up about css and apply your own styling to the form and if you get stuck, give us a shout

Comment: add class for your input tag ex. col-md-10;

Comment: @LaljiTadhani you mean `<div class="form-group col-md-10"` ?

Comment: no  - @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-10" } })

Comment: @LaljiTadhani that works! But unfortunately, labels go across the text box..do you know some cure for labels? In fact, I know why is this happening, cause my div is to tight for labels and text box..

Comment: <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-4"> change this class may be work <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3">

Comment: @LaljiTadhani nope, it is slightly different, but the same..thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take another look at Bootstrap documentation. If you're using Bootstrap 3.x, you should not be using `span*` (that belong to Bootstrap 2.x). `span*` have been replaced with `col-md-*`.

You can refer to [this migration guide](http://getbootstrap.com/migration).

Also, you should place all of your `.form-group` elements inside a `.form-horizontal` container.

Comment: Good advice, in general, but this has nothing to do with the OP's specific issue here.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply not giving the elements enough room. Your form is restricted to 4 columns and then your label is restricted to 2 columns. Essentially, the form is 4/12 of the total available width, then your label is 2/12 of *that*, which means overall your label is only 1/18 of the total available width. Just give it some more breathing room. Perhaps make your form `col-md-6` or `col-md-8` and your label something like `col-md-3`. Or if you want to stick with `col-md-4` for the whole form, increase your label to something like `col-md-4`.